# How to get current item index using Knockoutjs + Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a list of tasks I'm trying to display using Bootstrap Carousel and KnockoutJS. The user can view all the available tasks using the controls (arrows). Above that I want to display the index of the current visible task (li).

```
<ul id="slidercontent" class="carousel-indicators" data-bind="foreach: Tasks">
<li data-target="#taskCarousel" data-bind="attr: { 'data-slide-to': $index }"></li></ul>
```

My controls are outside that div but work perfectly.

```
<div class="tasks-carousel-controls">
                <!-- ko if: $root.Tasks().length > 1 -->
                <a class="left icon-chevron-left" href="#taskCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right icon-chevron-right" href="#taskCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
```

And then I have another div where I say which is the index of the tasks, like 'X out of Y', where X is my current index and Y is the length of my observable array.

I think the best solution would be to have a binding to some observable whose value is the object with the class = 'active' but I'm not being very successfully :/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$('body').on('click', '.tasks-carousel-controls a', function() {
     var slideIdx = $('#taskCarousel').find('.active').index();
     $('#divId').html('Slide '+slideIdx+' out of 5');
});
```

Where taskCarousel is the id of your bootstrap carousel and divId is the id of your div that you want to display index in.